# How do I remove the 'Content Security Policy' on my node express api?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, content-security-policy

I'm starting to learn node to build an web api using express with Typescript.

My goal is to build an api that consume a module called "psn-api" that give information from Psn(Playstation Network) logged user.

But when I try to call the module function that call an external API I get an error saying 'Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico (“default-src”).'

Is there a configuration on node that I need to make to disable this Security Policy?

```
import express from 'express';
import { exchangeCodeForAccessToken, exchangeNpssoForCode,getUserTrophyProfileSummary } from "psn-api";

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})

const myNpsso = "userToken";

app.get('/trophySummary', (req, res) => {
  var result = getUserTrophySummary();
  res.send(result)
})

async function getUserTrophySummary(){
  // We'll exchange your NPSSO for a special access code.
const accessCode = await exchangeNpssoForCode(myNpsso);

// We can use the access code to get your access token and refresh token.
const authorization = await exchangeCodeForAccessToken(accessCode);

return getUserTrophyProfileSummary(authorization,"me");
}
```

I already try setting the res.header to many different configurations but no result

```
res.setHeader(
    'Content-Security-Policy', "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'"
  );
```

Comment: The CSP is usually set on the server that delivers the web site html content rather the API. What URL is the browser accessing when this error is thrown?

Comment: It happens when I try to use the 'trophySummary' that consume the external psn-api